# Can Autofac IStartable be used with NServiceBus when the startable component needs IBus?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, nservicebus, bootstrapping

The scenario here is that there is a component that needs to run some initialisation code on start-up. This is achieved by having the code implement `Autofac.IStartable.Start` and registering the code as `IStartable`.

This code is then used in several contexts: A couple of ASP.NET websites, an `NServiceBus.Host.exe` hosted NSB app and an Atlas based Windows Service. It worked fine in each.

A recent change has introduced constructor injected dependencies to this startup code that include, some levels deep, an instance of `NServiceBus.IBus`. When the code now runs inside the NServiceBus host, it throws a `ComponentNotRegisteredException` stating "The requested service 'NServiceBus.IBus' has not been registered."

Here is the endpoint configuration for the NServiceBus host (v4.7):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new CoreModule());
Configure.With().AutofacBuilder(builder.Build());
```

What appears to be happening is that the `IStartable.Start` method is getting executed when the `ContainerBuilder.Build()` method is called, which is understandable, but at this point `IBus` is not registered in the container.

When message handlers are later instantiated via NServiceBus, and where these have a dependency on `IBus`, the bus is correctly injected. This would indicate that NServiceBus is 'adding' a new registration to the container after the container has been built.

I have altered the startup code to implement `NServiceBus.IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops` and it then runs the `Start` method successfully in the NServiceBus hosted application. However, the `Start` method is not then executed from the ASP.NET application or the WindowsService.

The NServiceBus startup code in the web application is as follows:

```
var bus = Configure.With((typeof (CoreModule).Assembly
    .GetTypes().Where(t =>
        t.Namespace != null
        && t.Namespace.StartsWith("OurApp.Messages"))))
    .DefaultBuilder()
    .DisableTimeoutManager()
    .UseTransport<Msmq>()
    .PurgeOnStartup(false)
    .UnicastBus()
    .CreateBus()
    .Start();
```

This code is executed and the `bus` is then registered with a container builder as follows:

```
builder.Register(cb => bus).As<IBus>().SingleInstance();
```

So my double barrelled question: Can `Autofac.IStartable` still be used somehow in an NServiceBus hosted application, or is there a way of making an alternative common start-up/bootstrap mechanism work, such as `NServiceBus.IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops`?

Comment: In your code, it seems you are using the default container with NServiceBus, shouldn't u be passing your container to NServiceBus?

Comment: In the code that initialises the NServiceBus host, which is the first code fragment, the container is passed to NServiceBus. The code that initialises the bus for the web application (fragment number 2) is doing so only so the web app can send messages to the bus. There are no handlers in the web app. I guess this is connected to why `IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops` is not getting triggered in that instance.

Comment: Missed that! The code on the webapplication should still execute `IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops`, the only time that does not get executed is if the endpoint is configured as SendOnly

Comment: Yes, the IBus is only registered in the container when the bus is about to be started, so `IStartable` may not work in your scenario

Comment: In this instance the end point is only being used for sending, though I am not explicitly configuring it as such. The web app has no handlers. I guess this is why the `IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops` doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can `Autofac.IStartable` still be used somehow in an NServiceBus hosted application?

Yes, but not if the component has a dependency on `IBus`.

> Can `NServiceBus.IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops` be used as an alternative?

Only if you are handling NSB messages in each application. In my case the web site was only sending messages to remote endpoints and so this interface was not invoked.

My 'solution' to ensuring that startup code runs in both scenarios was two fold:

Firstly, implement both `Autofac.IStartable` and `NServiceBus.IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops` on the classes that needed to be run at startup. They have the same method signature, which is handy.

Secondly, register `Autofac.IStartable` implementations in the container only in the applications in which `NServiceBus.IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops` is *not* invoked. This was done by splitting their registration into a separate Autofac module which was only registered in those applications. That module looked like this:

```
public class StartablesModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load([NotNull] ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(
            typeof (StartablesModule).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<IStartable>())
            .As<IStartable>();
    }
}
```